# how to refresh grid view after deleting image from grid view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have saved images in @"/Documents/MyApp%d.png and i have an NSMutableArray in which i have set integer values. for eg my NSMutableArray contains (2,3,5,6,7,12,14,16) now in grid it will show me MyApp2,MyApp3,MyApp5 and so on(from array). this is my grid view 
[image]

let say i m clicking 3rd index of gridview which is MyApp5 and then it opens in swipeView. 
like this 
[image]

and when i click delete icon then it will delete this image . Remember i had (2,3,5,6,7,12,14,16) in nsmutablearray. and when i am deleting this image my values changes to this (2,3,6,7,12,14,16) it means it was successfully deleted but when i go back again on grid view it shows like this. 
[image]

i dont know where i am wrong. but when i will go back and come back to grid view again it will show properly all images.

I am using this code for gridView [link](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIGridView` in that project is a subclass of `UITableView`.  Did you try sending it the `reloadData` message?

Also, Apple reserves the `UI` prefix (and all other two-letter prefixes).  It's dangerous to use a class named `UIGridView` that didn't come from Apple.

Comment: i have reloaded my table on viewDidAppear.. 
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [table reloadData];
}

Comment: Have you verified that `viewDidAppear:` is being called when you need it to be?

Comment: yes. i had an issue before that all images disappear in gridview than i have added reload in viewDidAppear now atleast images before that index which is deleted are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a cellIdentifier as below; (define int reloader)
And then, when you need to reload tableview,try increasing reloader. 
I've written my reloadData function below, you can use it.

```
-(NSString *) getCellIdentifier:(NSInteger)index sectionindex:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",section] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i" , index] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", reloader];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [self getCellIdentifier:indexPath.row sectionindex:indexPath.section];
    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d,%d)", rowIndex, columnIndex];

    return cell;
}

-(void) reloadData{
    reloader++;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i want to reload data when that viewcontroller is appear. thats y i have called reloadData on my viewdidload method. whats different in both of them.?

Comment: viewdidload works only one time, it loads the view and that's it. If you want to work it every time view appears, you have to call it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.